# C++ Undefined reference to vtable when adding "using namespace std;"

Tags: c++

```
#include <QGraphicsScene>

using namespace std;

class Object
{
    public:
    Object(){};
    virtual ~Object(){};
    virtual void draw(QGraphicsScene * s, int x, int y){};
    virtual string get();
};
```

I get an error saying "undefined reference to vtable for Object". The error happens on both the constructor and the destructor. The error goes away when I delete the "using namespace std;" line. How can I fix this error without deleting that line? Or providing another method of using a string variable type?

Comment: Did you include or use a STL library?

Comment: The code is ill-formed in either case so you should fix the problem anyway (by providing bodies for your virtual functions).

Comment: It won't solve your problem, but you're probably better off deleting `using namespace std;` It can cause all sorts of weird errors. Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because a virtual method is declared but not defines, in your situation that's

```
virtual string get();
```

And somewhere in your code you are telling to the compiler to emit the vtable for `Object` by instantiating it, eg

```
Object* o = new Object();
```

You must define it, or if you want to let subclasses implement it, explicitly mark it as pure:

```
virtual string get() = 0;
```

In both situations (letting it unimplemented or mark it as pure) you won't be able to directly instantiate an `Object` instance, because the object has an incomplete implementation.